# java.lang.RuntimeException: Not a host:port pair:

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I wrote a Map-reduce program. While trying to run it , it is showing a run-time exception as follows

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Not a host:port pair: 
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:136)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getAddress(JobTracker.java:1807)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:410)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:54)
at com.homedepot.mm.rd.transactionmatching.hadoop.utils.TMHelper.driverConfig(TMHelper.java:83)
at com.homedepot.mm.rd.transactionmatching.hadoop.driver.TMDuplicateRemoverDriver.run(TMDuplicateRemoverDriver.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at com.homedepot.mm.rd.transactionmatching.hadoop.driver.TMDuplicateRemoverDriver.main(TMDuplicateRemoverDriver.java:111)
```

I couln't find the reason for this.Can any one help me out!

Comment: Check what do you have in `mapred-site.xml` file for the property: `mapreduce.jobtracker.address`

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have same versions of Hadoop on CLient and Server.

Also that your cluster machines are well specified in masters and slaves files in hadoop conf directory.